# Django ORM group by, and find latest item of each group (window functions)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm, window-functions

Say we have a model as below

```python
class Cake(models.Model):

    baked_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cake_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Now, there are multiple `Cake`s baked on the same day, and I need a query that will return me a monthly cake report which consists of each day of the month, and the names of the first and last cakes baked on that day.

For example, if the data is something like this:

```
baked_on        cake_name
11 Jan 12:30    Vanilla
11 Jan 14:30    Strawberry
11 Jan 20:45    Avocado
12 Jan 09:05    Raspberry
12 Jan 16:30    Sprinkles
12 Jan 20:11    Chocolate
```

My query's output should look like

```
date    first     last
11 Jan  Vanilla   Avocado
12 Jan  Raspberry Chocolate
```

How should I go about doing this in a single ORM call?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Django 2.0 introduced window functions that are made for that kind of queries. Simple answer for your question will be:

```
Cake.objects.annotate(
    first_cake=Window(
        expression=FirstValue('cake_name'),
        partition_by=[TruncDate('baked_on')],
        order_by=F('baked_on').asc(),
    ),
    last_cake=Window(
        expression=FirstValue('cake_name'),
        partition_by=[TruncDate('baked_on')],
        order_by=F('baked_on').desc(),
    ),
    day=TruncDate('baked_on'),
).distinct().values_list('day', 'first_cake', 'last_cake')
```

Why `FirstValue` in `last_cake`? That's becaues window query by default will traverse through each row and won't look ahead, so for every row, last row will be equal to current row. Using `last_row` together with descending sorting will fix that. Either that or you can define frame for which window query should work:

```
Cake.objects.annotate(
    first_cake=Window(
        expression=FirstValue('cake_name'),
        partition_by=[TruncDate('baked_on')],
        order_by=F('baked_on').asc(),
    ),
    last_cake=Window(
        expression=LastValue('cake_name'),
        partition_by=[TruncDate('baked_on')],
        order_by=F('baked_on').asc(),
        frame=ValueRange(),
    ),
    day=TruncDate('baked_on'),
).distinct().values_list('day', 'first_cake', 'last_cake')
```

Comment: Looks like a very clean solution, even though I don't completely understand it at first glance! Just to confirm, this isn't supported on Django 1.11 is it?

Comment: No, window expressions were introduced in 2.0 and are not available in 1.11.

Comment: How could you make this be custom outside of the TruncDate, Like if I wanted to use TruncMinute, but get 5 minute chunks instead of 1 minute chunks? I got this working using ur solution and used 1 minute chunks.

Comment: You can try to specify `partition_by` as follows: `[TruncHour('baked_on'), Cast(ExtractMinute('baked_on') / 5, IntegerField())]`.

Comment: @GwynBleidD any idea when I do that partition_by `Cast(ExtractMinute('baked_on') / 15, IntegerField())` i sometimes end up with more than 4 per hour. On average I'm getting 5 per hour instead of 4 per hour. I should be getting 3x less and on average im only getting 2.4x less.

Comment: It is probably rounding up or down depending on the case, so you are getting numbers from 0 to 4 inclusive. Try to tweak that formula, maybe introduce flooring there.

Comment: I think you're right. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'ExtractMinute' and 'int'`. Any idea what floor i can use here?

Comment: You can use [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to call `floor` function from postgresql.